# Don't break Linux "copy-on-select" in link dialog

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, user-experience

When I try to insert a link, I have a tab open with the page I want to link to, to avoid errors.

If I click the link-link, I get a dialog, where "http://" is already filled in. But to cut and paste my link, it would be more easy to mark the whole link, and paste that, instead of twiddling around with the mouse.

Note that there are two standard ways to copy/paste in Linux, one is more comfortable: You mark a text - in this case the url in the browser. You just mark it - no Ctrl-C or something requiered. Then you place the cursor at the target place, and just hit the middle mouse button. Whatever is marked is now pasted to the place where the cursor is. But the pre-marked field "http://" foils that attempt, because now, the last marked text isn't the url in another tab, but the useless text "http://".

Possible improvements:

1. let the field empty. (my preferred idea, should simply work)
2. give two alternative link fields, one with http:// but not marked, one without. I guess the "http://" has two purposes: make clear what is requiered, and help those, who like to type. Well, of corse, sometimes it is https. :)

The first idea is always the best one. :)

Here is an [image: screenshot of xfce4-dict] with brush as button (see comments for reason why). I don't know how easy this is with javascript. If you hit the brush, the textfield is cleared. The whole field is a plug-in for the (top)-panel, the improper frame shall show that.

Comment: When clicking the button, the "http://" is highlighted, so pasting (or pressing spacebar as in part 3) will automatically overwrite that. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: @user, what @Grace means is, if you *don't click* in the url field, you can Ctrl-V directly.

Comment: Yes, Grace Note seems right. I experienced 2 times minor problems but now it seems very easy. Maybe I can reproduce it another time in the complicated way. So long.

Comment: The edit changes things. Do you know of any website that also pre-selects content of input fields when they become active, but *without* that breaking your workflow? (And what about changing the title to *Don't break Linux "middle-click to paste selected text" in link dialog* or maybe *Don't break Linux "copy-on-select" in link dialog* or something like that?)

Comment: Ad 1: the editor already validates that the URL starts with `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://`, and simply prepends `http://` if none has been specified.

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, you're right, it seems possible. dict.leo.org has a 'clear'-Button to clear away the selectin. If I click clear, I can paste my active selection. http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=furchtbar

Comment: Ad ad 1: That was only a sidenote.

Comment: I doubt an extra button will be added in the interface. Any other sites that don't use such button? And the same in all browsers, I assume? (And I truly doubt the current question title makes clear what you want. It's quite a bad title, if you'd ask me...)

Comment: Yes, I changed the title, according to your suggestion. I don't understand 'the same for all browsers?'. It's a javascript thing in the browser, and a clipboard-thing, nothing specific to a special browser. I too don't understand '  Any other sites that don't use such button?' You mean websites, which present a premarked text like SE, and without 'clear' button? I don't know any. The ubuntu-Desktop has an task-bar-app, which can be used for a fast access to a dictionary (again) and this has a small brush to wipe the input field - i will provide a screenshot in the question.

Comment: Maybe another browser interacts differently with the OS as for telling it that something was selected? Likewise: maybe other websites use different JavaScript code to pre-select something, which does not interfere with the copy-on-select. Of course, the easiest solution would be to not pre-fill the input with `http://`, just like you suggested. Workaround: simply type `[your description](`, paste, type `)`.(Totally as an aside: I actually doubt the clipboard is used? But that doesn't matter for the feature request.)

Comment: Actually, `[]` are complicated to type in german keyboard layout with 10-finger system. Installing `chrome or konqueror` on linux isn't actually an option, because on low bandwith. Maybe later, or another user could test it? `Anybody out there?`.

Comment: Does the pre-selected text in the popup you get when clicking "link" (below any question or answer) make its way to your selection buffer? (Maybe related: [New "link" miniwindows don't copy-n-paste](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86836/new-link-miniwindows-dont-copy-n-paste).)

Comment: No. If I click the link button, a frameless, small window shows up, with predefined input 'http://' which is marked, but if I switch to another application, I can't paste this with a middle click. It doesn't make a difference, If I visit that window previously to give it the focus, the marking of `http://` automatically vanishs.