# New "link" miniwindows don't copy-n-paste in vimperator

Tags: support, permalink

When clicking "link" below a question or answer, one gets a popup with a pre-selected link:

[image: Share link popup]

I cannot get the selected text to *actually* copy and paste using vimperator on X11.

The old behavior was great; clicking the `link` would load that specific URL into the browser's location field, and then `y` would `yank` the URL into the selection buffer. Great success.

This new behavior, I can't get the text in the miniwindow into the selection buffer or the clipboard: `^X`, `^C`, right-click copy, right-click cut, *none* of those actually let me paste the URL later. Whatever cruft I might have in my selection buffer is pasted instead. Not much success.

Is there any chance of fixing this bug? Or am I the only one here using vimperator? :)

Comment: Reading your whole question, I understand that copy does not work either? As cutting does not make a lot of sense, maybe change the title to put the emphasis on copy then?

Comment: Another aside: as this is pre-selected, maybe you can paste using the middle mouse button without any further ado?

Comment: @Arjan, wish I could. It's all for show. :( The selected-look is all a big tease.

Comment: Odd; others complain that the pre-selected text destroys the older existing contents of that "middle-click to paste selected text" buffer (not to be confused with the clipboard): [Don't break Linux “copy-on-select” in link dialog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82165/dont-break-linux-copy-on-select-in-link-dialog). What behavior do you get there?

Comment: @Arjan, hah, I've never tried that little button before. I can type `[blah](shift+insert)` quickly enough that I never look for a button. Anyway, _that_ little thing destroys my selection buffer and inserts `d`, thirteen space+newlines, `d`, six space+newlines, `a`, newline. Amazing.

Comment: Amazing indeed. It shows `http://` on your screen, right?

Comment: (Ah, "selection buffer"! I *knew* there was a simple term for it!)

Comment: @Arjan, yeah, I'm as surprised as you :) The window showed `http://` just as one might expect, but pasting it into `vim` or (stupid, `bash`) gives `d \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \nd \n \n \n \n \n \na\n`. Where `\n` of course means _newline_. It must be bed time.

Comment: Any other selection of text on these sites just works as expected, I hope? And likewise when you type something yourself and select that? Or when you explicitly deselect and select the `http://` manually again? (Just to exclude odd HTTP Content-Type issues in vimperator, though simple text such as `http://` in UTF-8 really is the same as in ASCII, so I doubt there wold be any issues there.)

Comment: this is not a bug in us, this is a bug in vimperator -- http://vimperator.org/vimperator

Comment: @Arjan, Heh, I forgot: if I decide to change a comment I'm writing into an answer, I have to paste it into the edit control using `^V` (really, `^V^V`, the first one to send the second one through to the edit control) -- middle-click to paste will lose the entire first line. Once I figured out the workaround for that (`^V^V`) I haven't thought much about it since. :) As for the `http://` example, yeah, I tried de-selecting and re-selecting a few times, just to confirm that I really did see what I saw. :)

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, I sure wish I knew why SO is the only place that can trigger this behavior. :) Gmail, pragprog forums, launchpad, various bugzillas, amazon reviews, project euler, even my _bank_ :), everything else works fine. Just not SO. :(

Comment: talk about a corner case...